# Vector iterator and stop condition

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, break

I have a problem with stop condition of my infinite loop 'for'. I've declared two iterators for two vector's. Those vectors may contain diffrent number of elements (size of vectors are not equal - mostly).

OK so here's a piece of my code:

```
vector<int> even;
vector<int> odd;
vector<int>::iterator itEven;
vector<int>::iterator itOdd;
```

As the name says vector are storing even and odd integers. After filling my vector's with data i want to display content of both vector alternately. I'm doing it here:

```
for(itEven = even.begin(), itOdd = odd.begin() ;; itEven ++, itOdd ++){
    if(itEven != even.end())
        printf("%d ", *itEven);
    if(itOdd != odd.end())
        printf("%d ", *itOdd);
    if(itEven == even.end() && itOdd == odd.end())
        break;
}
```

My break instruction works only if vector cointains same number of elements. There's something wrong and I'm getting infinite loop when first vector holding one element and second holding three - for example.

I hope my description of a problem was clear for you, thanks for any respones and help.

Comment: What would you expect when you increment both iterators the same number of times?

Comment: You'd be better off iterating the iterators inside the loop instead of in the for loop to better control the break condition

Comment: Incrementing any *past the end* iterator from the standard library results in UB. A past the end iterator is *only* an iterator that points to the element one past the end. An iterator that points 2+ past the end is **not** equal to the iterator returned by calling `end`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior if both vectors have different sizes :

In your for loop, **you increment the iterators even when they went past out the `end()` :**

```
 itEven ++, itOdd ++ // Once you reach the end of one, you continue to increment its iterator
```

One of them (the iterator of the smaller vector) will never pass your test:

```
if(itEven == even.end() && itOdd == odd.end())
        break;
```

You want to do those increments only until the `end()` of each, probably within a `while()` loop, something like :

```
while(true){
    if(itEven != even.end())
        printf("%d ", *itEven++);
    if(itOdd != odd.end())
        printf("%d ", *itOdd++);
    if(itEven == even.end() && itOdd == odd.end())
        break;
}
```

**Note:**

Prefer `std::cout` to `printf`

Comment: Thanks for help now I've understood my mistake :-) `printf()` iż for SPOJ Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You are incrementing the iterator of the shorter list past the end of the list.  This leads to undefined behaviour.  In your case appears it appears the iterator is no longer equal to end.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to loop all the way through both vectors then you need to stop incrementing when one of them hits the end. Since you'll be conditionally incrementing, put that code in the for body and move the break condition to the for header:

```
for(itEven = even.begin(), itOdd = odd.begin(); itEven != even.end() || itOdd != odd.end();){
    //Do things...

    //Conditionally increment both iterators
    if(itEven != even.end()) itEven++;
    if(itOdd != odd.end()) itOdd++;
}
```

Comment: You've got `==` instead of `!=` as the end condition.  And because you're and'ing the conditions, the conditions you put on the increment can be dropped.  But you'll need loops following for the one vector you've not finished with.

Comment: @JamesKanze good call, I brain farted and flipped the whole end condition. Edited. Also, this one loop will be enough, no need for two.

Comment: That's one way to do it.  The other would be to and the two conditions, and use loops for the left-over elements after this loop.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes but we don't have enough information on what `//Do things...` is actually doing, so there's no way to know what the OP actually needs...

Answer (score 0):

```
for(itEven = even.begin(), itOdd = odd.begin() ;; ){
  if(itEven != even.end()){
    printf("%d ", *itEven);
    itEven ++;
  }
  if(itOdd != odd.end()){
    printf("%d ", *itOdd);
    itodd ++;
  }
  if(itEven == even.end() && itOdd == odd.end()){break;}
}
```

This should work as you want.